# Malware "System Fix" icon is still showing up

Tags: windows, malware, spyware, malware-removal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

My PC was recently infected by System Fix Malware/Spyware which has been removed by steps mentioned listed [here](http://www.myantispyware.com/2011/11/15/how-to-remove-system-fix-virus/) and [here](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/virus-removal/remove-system-fix).

After following above links, I still see the System Fix installed under my start menu, as a desktop shortcut. I do NOT see it in the list of programs installed in control panel.

OS: Windows XP SP3

Answer (score 1):

Scan with [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org) and possibly with something like [ComboFix](http://www.combofix.org/download.php) to be totally sure you are clean...

Lots of virus & spyware removal guides all over the 'net.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've only got the shortcuts left hanging around.  Make sure that they are *only* shortcuts, and delete them.

Then, scan the system again with your choice of malware removal tool(s) and/or antivirus.  If an infection is still present, it's probably time for a rebuild.